# Why does my re.search command is not working?

Tags: python, regex, wlst

I have this 'if' condition inside my script:

```
if ( re.search(argVariable, newArgs) ):
```

However it fails when I passed on a certain value for 'argVariable'

Sample output:

```
Searching for the argument: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
argVariable: "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" is MISSING, Adding...
```

I'm sure that my 'newArgs' variable already has it. (See below)

```
New args: -Xverbosetimestamp -Xverbose:memory -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that I need to re.escape the actual value right before I use it. Then I need to use the compiled version to avoid special characters inside the variable to be interpreted like a regex' special character:

```
compiledArgVariable = re.compile(re.escape(argVariable))
if ( re.search(compiledArgVariable, newArgs) ):
```

Sample output shows that it finds the exact value:

```
argVariable: "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" found to be an EXISTING argument. Checking if it has the correct value...
"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" HAS the correct value. Skipping..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your regex,  use [re.escape()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
escapedRegex = re.escape(regex)
```